# Android does startActivity() calls get stacked?

Tags: android, start-activity

I have recently started working with android. So I am in the initial stages of learning.

The question is: when we call startActivty(Intent) in the middle of execution of another activity.I actually thought that startActivity() will simply jump into the activity called. Isn't it the case? does it simply stacks the call to the activity?
I am getting this doubt bcoz..I actually have a program in which Activity A has a loop. Some where in the middle of loop Activity B is called. I want activity A to resume with the loop only when activity B finishes. I have made a call in A's loop like this:

```
in = new Intent(this,MyChoiceActivity.class);
in.putExtra("McObj", mc);
startActivity(in);
finish();
```

So What happens is Activity A calls B, but B is not entered, A simply resumes the loop and again calls B, simply the calls to B are stacked and once the loop in A completes, one by one calls to B in stack are executed so finally the first call to B is executed last(last in first out)...But I dont want the order to change...If A calls B, it should simply go and execute B and only then come to the loop..what should I do to accomplish this?

Comment: read this..you will get to know about Activity life cycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: add to the previous comment, finish(); is used when you want to go to the next activity and destroy current one. If you go to Activity B and call finish on Activity A, then you can't go back to Activity A from Activity B by pressing Back button.

Comment: @Sharj..I know that..I am actually trying to pass questions from activity A to Activity B..It's actually done in a loop..with each iteration a question is passed to the next activity..mc object there, contains the question...initially I implemented that without using finish..even then the same thing happened..calls to B are stacked..what should I do to avoid stacking of calls? any idea?

Comment: You can't have a loop on the UI thread like that and obey the requirement of the android API that you promptly return from all UI thread **event methods**.  Instead, organize your program as a state machine ie a "what will I do, next time I receive an event with makes it proper to do something"  If you need to generate extra events to pump through the states you can use a timer and runOnUiThread().

Comment: @Chris..I'll remember that..Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Your activity can be busy and just 'be there'. If you start a new activity while your activity is really doing something, it will not 'wait' until the other activity is finished: both can be around at the same time.
If it *would* do this, it would have you end up with a lot of busy-waiting processes, so luckily this is not what happens.

See the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to find out more about what an activity is (it is *not* just another class as you are using it now, it starts a separate thing that hangs around next to (not instead of / on top of) your current activity).

Instead, beacuse these things go rather asynchronous, you might want to use a different approach: use an `ActivityForResult`, and start a new one when you get that result.

Comment: So if I use startActivityForResult() can I avoid stacking of calls to B?

Comment: No, you **do not** get to "busy wait" on the ui thread in Android.

Comment: @ChrisStratton you are correct, I was trying to say (but not doing a very well job) that that would be the case if it would work like the OP expects it to work. THe point I was trying to make was that you don't get that, and that's why it works differently :)  .. Lemme see if I can fix it up.

Comment: @user2784307 if you use activityforresult you start the activity and then stop doing stuff. But if the activity is finished, your callback will be called and you can do something with the result (even re-start the same activity again).